# jQuery appendTo making multiple copies

Tags: jquery

I have a basic function that shifts one div into another, when I have multiple divs with the same class name it duplicates the div.

In my fiddle/example at the moment it takes a copy of all four orange squares and puts them inside all of the red squares

What I want is the orange square below each red square to move inside the red square so each red square will only have one orange square inside, the one below it.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/qrou7upr/3/)

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.orange').appendTo('.red');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `$('.orange')` gets all the divs with the class orange. (There are four.) What you want to do is to loop through the containers and just get the `div.orange` there.

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $('.container').each(function (idx, elm) {
      var $container = $(elm);
      var $red = $container.children('.red');
      var $orange = $container.children('.orange');
      $orange.appendTo($red);
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocqajy3s/).

Comment: Thanks for the help!